# App inventor share file with message via facebook

Tags: app-inventor

I'm building an app with Google's App Inventor, and user uses his/her camera, takes a pictures, then taps Share and choose a program from list. 
I what when sharing the image with Facebook to show a given message, but it dosn't work.

My quession is how I willl get the same message that appears in gmail sharing as well as in facebook sharing.

Thank you.!

Comment: you can share text using this [method](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/CgB86rO-_vg/iPOPlUZ6EZsJ), but I don't think, you can share an image...

Comment: see also this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/C9NzizR8B8s/HScwBZdv8gEJ) in the App Inventor forum